# Relationship between models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and working on my first app. What I want to achieve is an facebook like groups with their own walls and comments. Sounds pretty easy :)

I currently have 3 models: Group, Post and Comment. Here's the code:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :affiliation, :group_name, :group_type, :string

  validates :group_name, :presence => true
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "id"
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :posted_by, :posted_by_uid

  validates :body, :presence => true
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :commenter

  belongs_to :post
end
```

I managed to properly relate Comments to Posts. Its views are OK. But when I tried to relate Posts to Groups for some reason Posts (with corresponding Comments) are not Showing up.

Here's the snippet from Show view:

```
<b>Posts</b>
<%= render @group.posts %>
```

Posts partial (_post.html.erb in Posts forlder)

```
<h1>New post</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>

<p>
  <b> Content </b>
  <%= @post.body %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @post.comments %>  

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%=  render "comments/form" %>
<br />
```

PS I have no idea why I added foreign key, but without it i would get error (column group.posts.id doesn't exist), I just somehow figured it out comparing with other questions on stackoverflow that foreign key might choose the problem. It did, but it's not showing Posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the posts table has a column `group_id`, then you should be able to remove the foreign key part.

If `@group` doesn't have any posts then it won't render the partial. Calling `@group.posts` will return an array, which is then iterated over and render is called for each object. If there are no posts then an empty array is returned, and the partial won't be rendered.

Change it to the following:

groups#show view:

```
<h1>New post</h1>
<%= render 'posts/form' %>

<b>Posts</b>
<%= render @group.posts %>
```

_post.html.erb partial:

```
<p>
  <b> Content </b>
  <%= @post.body %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @post.comments %>  

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>
<br />
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer. I rechecked the partial and looks like it's named as _post.html.erb

Comment: Thanks for the group_id idea! Now i understand how it works :)

Comment: Inside `_post.html.erb` try changing `@post` to just `post`. Make sure to add any errors you're getting to your question.

Comment: Hmm, pages loads normally (without showing partial) I wonder maybe it's not loading the partial at all.

Comment: Have you checked that `@group` actually has posts?

Comment: It doesn't. Yet. But _post partial is supposed to render the form too. Or did you mean something else? (like checking models)

Comment: Aah, i found the gap in my logic!  but now i get the following error 
NoMethodError in Groups#show 
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class for posts partial form.

Comment: 1: <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @post.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29086/discussion-between-luke-and-mind-blank)